# Как открыть файл с русским текстом в Python3 и разбить текст на предложения используя nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, nltk

Необходимо обрабатывать русскоязычный текст(ы) большого объёма. Насколько я разобрался в данном вопросе, при работе с помощью библиотеки **nltk** весь текст надо переводить в байтовые строки.

Подскажите примерный алгоритм при условии, что сначала весь текст хранится в текстовых файлах, после чего его надо разбить на предложения и занести в БД (keychain)?

Comment: Так, а в чем, собственно, вопрос? Перевести текст в байтовый массив?

Comment: По крайней мере у меня nltk успешно работает и с небайтовыми строками тоже

Comment: Вообще у них [есть книга](http://www.nltk.org/book) описывающая работу с библиотекой и в ней есть куча примеров. Насколько я вижу [текст должен быть Unicode](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html#fig-unicode) при работе с ним, но ничего про обязательность байтовых строк.

Comment: Текстовый файл около 7-8 МБ каждый в кодировке UTF-8
За книгу спасибо - забыл про нее!  Плюс надо разбивать по предложениям - сплошная магия регулярных выражений.

Comment: Поясните для чего вам надо разбивать текст по предложениям. Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Базу с предложениями

Comment: Несмотря на то что текст в юникоде вылетает ошибка `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: В заголовке вопроса указано - Python3 - если быть точным Python 3.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
In [59]: from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

In [60]: txt = open(r'C:\download\voyna_i_mir_tom_1.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()

In [61]: sents = sent_tokenize(txt)

In [62]: len(sents)
Out[62]: 8033
```

первые десять предложений:

```
In [63]: sents[:10]
Out[63]:
['Том I\n\nЛев Николаевич Толстой\n\nВОЙНА И МИР\n\nТом 1\n\n\n\nЧАСТЬ ПЕРВАЯ\n\n\n\nI\n\n—\xa0Еh bien, mon prince.',
 'Genes et Lucques ne sont plus que des apanages, des поместья, de la famille Buonaparte.',
 "Non, je vous previens, que si vous ne me dites pas, que nous avons la guerre, si vous vous permettez encore de pallier toute
s les infamies, toutes les atrocites de cet Antichrist (ma parole, j'y crois) — je ne vous connais plus, vous n'etes plus mon
ami, vous n'etes plus мой верный раб, comme vous dites.",
 '[Ну, что, князь, Генуа и Лукка стали не больше, как поместьями фамилии Бонапарте.',
 'Нет, я вас предупреждаю, если вы мне не скажете, что у нас война, если вы еще позволите себе защищать все гадости, все ужасы
 этого Антихриста (право, я верю, что он Антихрист)\xa0— я вас больше не знаю, вы уж не друг мой, вы уж не мой верный раб, как
 вы говорите. ]',
 'Ну, здравствуйте, здравствуйте.',
 'Je vois que je vous fais peur, [Я вижу, что я вас пугаю, ] садитесь и рассказывайте.',
 'Так говорила в июле 1805 года известная Анна Павловна Шерер, фрейлина и приближенная императрицы Марии Феодоровны, встречая
важного и чиновного князя Василия, первого приехавшего на ее вечер.',
 'Анна Павловна кашляла несколько дней, у нее был грипп, как она говорила (грипп был тогда новое слово, употреблявшееся только
 редкими).',
 "В записочках, разосланных утром с красным лакеем, было написано без различия во всех:\n\n«Si vous n'avez rien de mieux a fai
re, M. le comte (или mon prince), et si la perspective de passer la soiree chez une pauvre malade ne vous effraye pas trop, je
 serai charmee de vous voir chez moi entre 7 et 10 heures."]
```

Comment: А кто потерял диакритические знаки во французской части текста? Их уже не было в `*.txt`, с ними не справился `ntlk`, с ними не справился терминал или движок `stackoverflow`?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, я скачал файл в `CP1251` кодировке - соответственно их там уже не было и уже потом сохранил его в `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью re:

```
import re
result = re.split(r'\n', yourtext)
```