# Как в методе find() использовать список?

Tags: python, парсер, бот

Пытаюсь сделать бота который знает определённые команды, и дабы не писать каждый раз

```
if otvet == "шутка":
    shutka()
elif otvet == "анекдот"
    shutka()
```

Я хотел сделать список ключевых слов, при нахождении хотябы одного из элементов списка в строке, запустить функцию. В моей голове это выглядит так:

```
key = ["шутка", "анекдот", "смешно"]
if key in otvet:
    shutka()
```

Но тут же ошибка, мол не могу конвертировать список в строку.

Заметьте: otvet может быть целым предложением, надо искать в предложении один из элементов списка и при находке запустить функцию.
Как реализовать мою задумку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы узнать содержит ли ответ `answer` одно из заданных в списке ключевых слов `keywords`:

```
answer = 'текст, который может содержать слово шутка или другие слова'
keywords = ["шутка", "анекдот", "смешно"]
if any(word in answer for word in keywords)
    print('шутка')
```

Чтобы только раз просматривать `answer` или для более сложных критериев, можно регулярные выражения использовать:

```
import regex  # $ pip install regex

answer = 'текст, который может содержать слово шутка или другие слова'
if regex.search(r"\L<words>", answer, words=keywords):
    print('шутка')
```

[named lists] можно с помощью `re` модуля из стандартной библиотеки реализовать: [How to match any string from a list of strings in regular expressions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33406313/4279)

```
import re

if re.search(r'шутка|анекдот|смешно', answer):
    print('шутка')
```

Ссылки на более эффективные алгоритмы для поиска нескольких подстрок одновременно в большом тексте см. в [Поиск строк в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628508/23044).

Команды для бота могут иметь предопределённую структуру. К примеру, если команда должна начинаться на одно из заданных слов, то можно просто [`str.startswith` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) использовать:

```
answer = 'анекдот: Встречаются в море два военных корабля - ...'
if answer.startswith(("шутка", "анекдот", "смешно")):
    print('анекдот')
```

И даже если ответ может более свободную структуру иметь, то всё равно может быть полезным сперва входной текст на лексемы разбить. К примеру, текст, содержащий`print("abc")` в Питоне, это список следующих лексем:

```
$ python3 -mtokenize <<< 'print("abc")'
0,0-0,0:            ENCODING       'utf-8'        
1,0-1,5:            NAME           'print'        
1,5-1,6:            OP             '('            
1,6-1,11:           STRING         '"abc"'        
1,11-1,12:          OP             ')'            
1,12-1,13:          NEWLINE        '\n'           
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

Подобное разбиение может быть удобно с помощью регулярных выражений проводить. К примеру, чтобы получить список слов:

```
import re

print(re.findall(r'\w+', 'какие-то слова. Ещё, и ещё.'))
# -> ['какие', 'то', 'слова', 'Ещё', 'и', 'ещё']
```

Для разбиения текста на предложения см. [Как открыть файл с русским текстом в Python3 и разбить текст на предложения используя nltk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717296/23044).

Если текст свободный, то перед сравнением может быть полезно корень слова получить (чтобы найти разные формы слова):

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer  # $ pip install nltk

stemmer = SnowballStemmer("russian") 
answer = 'не понял шутки'
print(*map(stemmer.stem, answer.split()))
# -> не поня шутк
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, этот материал ответил на вопросы которые я ещё не задал) Ценю ваш подробный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

key - это список. Тогда надо не **if key in otvet:**

```
if otvet in key:

for tag in key:
    if otvet.find(tag)!=-1:
        print(tag, "found in ", otvet)
```

Comment: Я понял вашу логику, но ведь ответ может быть целым предложением. Надо искать хотя бы один из элементов списка в ответе (который, повторяюсь, может быть целым предложением), и при находке, запустить функцию.

Comment: Тогда надо пользоваться поиском по строке.

Comment: да, только я не находил нужную мне инфу.

Comment: @WiLoBasic нужно правильно искать.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не использовать `any` с проверкой на вхождение ключевых слов в строку?

```
keys = ["шутка", "анекдот", "смешно"]
if any(x in otvet for x in keys):
    shutka()
```

Comment: Спасибо, не смотря на то что выше есть очень интересный код, он очень подробно осуществляет мою задумку, но использовать я буду ваш код. Он для меня интуитивней (я начинаю изучать питон) и проще что ли, но выполняет свою функцию. Спасибо!

Comment: Как раз хотел написать, что не увидел данный вариант в посте @jfs и что стоило бы принять не мой, а его ответ