# Как мне выделить предложения в [українська] тексте?

Tags: python

> Как мне выделить предложения в тексте? Например одно предложение текста - один элемент списка.

Пример текста:

```
Остап Вишня. Мисливськi усмiшки (збiрка)


   ВIДКРИТТЯ ОХОТИ
   Власне кажучи, щороку "Вiдкриття полювання" буває двiчi: першого серпня
на  птицю,  а  першого  листопада  на  звiра,  але   якось   уже   -   так
утрадицiйнилося, що  за  урочисте,  коли  хочете,  свято  серед  мисливцiв
вважається перше вiдкриття, коли пiсля довгої перерви у вас у руках  знову
улюблена вами рушниця i ви  знову  маєте  змогу  не  тiльки,  сказать  би,
поповнити  свої  продовольчi  ресурси,  не  тiльки  допомогти  державi   в
м'ясозаготiвлях, а й задовольнити себе  як  природознавця,  природофiла  й
спортсмена.
   Полювання, як бачите, не якась там легковажна дурничка, не дрiбничка, а
дуже й дуже поважна справа, особливо для таких громадян, як ми з вами...
   * * *
   Вiдкриття...
   Скiльки турбот,  хвилювання,  нервозностi,  доки  все  в  тебе  буде  в
порядку: i рушниця, i набої, i одежа, i рюкзак,  -  одне  слово,  все,  що
потрiбно для серйозного, добутливого полювання...
   А куди їхати?!
   А з ким їхати?!
   Куди їхати?!
   Ну, як ви одразу  зможете  вирiшити,  куди  їхати,  коли  сьогоднi  вам
кажуть:
   - Бiля Борисполя, на озерах, качви тiєї, ну,  як  хмари!  Повiрите,  як
випливуть, ну, як  тої  ряски!  Одне  одного  просто  давлять.  Оце  вчора
приїздила звiдтам молодиця, так казала, що її свекровi кум його казав,  що
кумова баба чула од свахи, що та сама бачила, як коноплi мочила,  що  нема
куди через тую качву коноплини ткнути! Поїдемо, га?!
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант `"текст".split(".")` Это конечно не идеально решение но уже проще работать с более короткими строками.

Comment: регуляркой "знак.!?-пробел-большаябуква"

Comment: Регулярки еще не учили, ты можешь написать полностью ?

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/tokenizing-words-and-sentences-with-nltk/

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как открыть файл с русским текстом в Python3 и разбить текст на предложения используя nltk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717296/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, нужно сначала определиться с правилами определения предложений. В тексте вижу диалоги, например. Текст перед ним будет считаться за отдельное предложение или нет? Еще есть какие-то ***. Их нужно выводить?
Если определить задание как - найти все подстроки, начинающиеся с заглавной буквы и заканчивающиеся точкой, вопросит. или воскл. знаком, то регулярка будет выглядеть примено так:

```
re.findall(r'[A-ZА-Я].*?[!?\.]{1}', text)
```

Но если продолжить добавлять условия, типа диалогов, * или двойных знаков ?!, то регулярное выражение начнет превращаться в монстра, написать которого под силу только опытному регулярщику.

Если это задача обучающая, то лучше воспользоваться тем, на закрепление чего она рассчитана. Если прикладная задача, то поискать какую-нибудь библиотеку (например NLTK, как в комментах советуют)